# Excel: reference to range in other sheet with integer input

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I want to write this formula:

`=Sheet1!$A$1:$C$9`

using an input of seperate cells containing the integer coordinates: `1, 1, 3, 9.`

How can I solve this problem with using worksheet functions? (Not VBA code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might be in the wrong order, but:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(3,9)))
```

Comment: Yes it works but I need to know how to merge such a statement with a reference to another sheet. Ex: =SUM(Sheet1!INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(3,9))) which returns error

Comment: =SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & ADDRESS(1,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(3,9))) does the trick. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Is the sheet name a given? Assuming yes then try using OFFSET like this:

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,Z1-1,Z2-1,Z3,Z4)

Where Z1 to Z4 contain, 1 (for start row position), 1 (for start column position), 9 ( for height of range) and 3 (for width of range) respectively.

First argument is always A1

If you want 3 and 9 to represent end point rather than size then use Z3-Z1+1 and Z4- Z2+1

If you can't make that work then a less ambiguous set of input values would be useful - what range do you expect if inputs are 4, 5, 6 and 7?

Note that to "see" the output you need to use the OFFSET function in context, e.g. within a function that expects a range like SUM

Comment: I get #REF! (invalid reference error) when trying the formula you stated. But if I type in the numbers directely instead of the cell names, I get the value of A1. Yes, the sheet has a pre-defined name.

Comment: I'm surprised you get #REF! did you use exactly the formula I suggested? If you use OFFSET on it's own in a single cell then you can't see the whole contents (because OFFSET is returning a range and you can't see that in one cell). What is displayed depends on **where** you put the formula. To see exactly what is returned select the cell with the formula, press F2 and then F9